# Populate Dropdown 2 based on Dropdown 1 selection

Tags: angularjs

I am able to populate 2 dropdowns directly from database.  My problem is, the 2nd dropdown values has to be populated based on the 1st dropdown selection.  Since i am new to Angular, i m not able to figure that out, can someone help me out with this.

```
<select id="OfficeId" name="OfficeId" ng-model="item.OfficeId"
        ng-options="item.OfficeId as item.OfficeName for item in Offices">
    <option value="" selected>Select the Office</option>
</select>
<select id="OBJ" name="OBJ" ng-model="item.OfficeOBJId"
        ng-options="item.OfficeOBJId as item.OBJId for item in Codes">
    <option value="" selected>Select OBJ Code</option>
</select>

myApp.factory('OfficeNames', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'api/Office/:id',
        { id: '@id' },
        { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
    );
});     

myApp.factory('OfficeObjCode', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'api/OfficeObj/:id',
        { id: '@id' },
        { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
    );
});

function OfficeCtrl($scope, $location, OfficeNames) {
    $scope.Offices = OfficeNames.query();
}

function OfficeObjCtrl($scope, $location, OfficeObjCode) {
    $scope.Codes = OfficeObjCode.query();
}
```

Note: I am using Web API/Angular/Petapoco/SQL Server

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I order to help us help you better, I _strongly_ suggest that you post whatever relevant code you already have.

Answer (score 14):

You shouldn't need 2 controllers for this, in fact that is probably one of the problems.
Once they are within the same scope you can easily tie them together.  Use `ng-change` on the first option to trigger a function that gets the values to populate the second option.

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Xku9z/

Also, you can use `ng-show` with the second select's options array length to only show the second select when it has been populated.

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Xku9z/1/

Comment: How can i adapt your example to populate cities after selecting a state calling http.get and  using this Json format: `$scope.states=[{"id":'1',"name":'Michigan',"cities":[{'id':'1','name':'Detroit'},{'id':'2','name':'Flint'}]}];`

Comment: You are going to want to have a list of states and then a list of cities for each state (essentially 50 city lists, 1 list per state).  After the state is selected, you would use that value in a `$http.get` call to obtain the list of cities for that state.  Then just set that list in scope.  Using a single list of states that also contains cities, you would not need to get the cites, as you would already have them with the states.

Comment: Do not use `ng-if`. As the author says to use `ng-show` to the second dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
<select id="OfficeId" name="OfficeId" ng-model="item.OfficeId"
    ng-options="item.OfficeId as item.OfficeName for item in Offices" ng-change="updateObjects(item.OfficeId)">
<option value="" selected>Select the Office</option>
```

```
<select id="OBJ" name="OBJ" ng-model="item.OfficeOBJId"
    ng-options="item.OfficeOBJId as item.OBJId for item in Codes">
<option value="" selected>Select OBJ Code</option>
```

With javascript you just need only one controller, the office controller:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('OfficeCtrl', 
['$scope','$location','OfficeNames','OfficeObjCode',function($scope, 
$location, OfficeNames,OfficeObjCode)
{
$scope.Offices=OfficeNames.query();

$scope.updateObjects =function(office_id)
{`// take {{office_id}} to server to pick codes based 
    //on that office id and
    // then assign them to $scope.codes..`

$scope.Codes = 'what you came back with';
}

}).factory('OfficeNames', function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    'api/Office/:id',
    { id: '@id' },
    { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
);
}).factory('OfficeObjCode', function ($resource) {
return $resource(
    'api/OfficeObj/:id',
    { id: '@id' },
    { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented like following, Hope it helps :)

Controller code

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.key_options = [
    {table:"Table_1",key:"age_flg",key_label:"Age"},
    {table:"Table_1",key:"ethnicity_flg",key_label:"Ethnicity"},
    {table:"Table_2",tab_label:"Table 2",key:"green_flg",key_label:"Green Flag"},
    {table:"Table_2",tab_label:"Table 2",key:"life_flg",key_label:"Life Flag"}
    ];
    $scope.options = [
    {table:"Table_1",tab_label:"Table 1"},
    {table:"Table_2",tab_label:"Table 2"}
    ];

$scope.sel = function(){
    if($scope.key_attr){
    console.log($scope.sel_attr['table']);
    console.log($scope.key_attr['key']);
};
}
});
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="sel_attr" ng-init="sel_attr = options[0]" ng-options="attr['tab_label'] for attr in options"></select>
<select ng-model="key_attr" ng-init="key_attr = key_options[0]" ng-options="attr['key_label'] for attr in key_options |filter: {table: sel_attr['table']}" ng-change="sel()"></select>
</body>
</html>
```