# Multiple binded dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

There is a problem that I faced in my project.
I have to use multiple binded dropdowns where one dropdown depends on previouses selected item.
For example, I have a class Person that has Country, Region and City, all three are selected from dropdown. 
Region dropdown depends on selected item of Country dropdown, i.e. Region dropdown has to contain the list of regions that belong to the selected country; and City dropdown is loaded after region is selected by user and contains only cities that belong to the selected region.

I have tried to do it like it is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Xku9z/1/, but it didn't work. After I "filter" the source of depending dropdowns and pass it through the scope, it is not reloading and the options of depending dropdowns remain the same.

Then I tried to fill options of dropdown manually in controller and then load it into dropdown.

```
<div data-ng-controller="spLocationControllers">
    <select ui-select2 ng-model="person.country_id" id="cbCountry" data-ng-change="updateCountry()">
    <option data-ng-repeat="item in spCountryList" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div data-ng-controller="spLocationControllers">
  <select data-ng-model="person.region_id" id="cbRegion" data-ng-change="updateRegion()"></select>
</div>


<div data-ng-controller="spLocationControllers">
   <select data-ng-model="person.district_id" id="cbCity"></select>
</div>
```

.

```
var listCountry = [{id: 1, name: "Country - 1"}, 
                 {id: 2, name: "Country - 2"},
                 {id: 3, name: "Country - 3"}];

var listRegion = [{id: 1, name: "Region - 1.1", countryId: 1},
                {id: 2, name: "Region - 1.2", countryId: 1},
                {id: 3, name: "Region - 2.1", countryId: 2},
                {id: 4, name: "Region - 2.2", countryId: 2},
                {id: 5, name: "Region - 3.1", countryId: 3},
                {id: 6, name: "Region - 3.2", countryId: 4}];

var listCity = [{id: 1, name: "City - 1.1", RegionId: 1},
                {id: 2, name: "City - 1.2", RegionId: 2},
                {id: 3, name: "City - 2.1", RegionId: 3},
                {id: 4, name: "City - 2.2", RegionId: 4},
                {id: 5, name: "City - 3.1", RegionId: 5},
                {id: 6, name: "City - 3.1", RegionId: 6}];


function spLocationControllers($scope)
{
    $scope.updateCountry = function()
    {
       var strOption = '<option value=-1> </option>';
       var cbv = $("#cbCountry option:selected").val();
       /*doing something with data and get to strOptions the list of regions that belong to selected country
   for example, if in cbCounty user selects "Country - 2" then strOptions would be something like this:
   '<option value=-1> </option> 
    <option value=3> Region - 2.1 </option>
    <option value=4> Region - 2.2 </option>'
   */

     $('#cbRegion')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append(strOption)
        ;
}
$scope.updateRegion = function()
{
   var strOption = '<option value=-1> </option>';
   var cbv = $("#cbRegion option:selected").val();
   /* forming corresponding list of cities and setting this list to strOptions  */

     $('#cbCity')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append(strOption)
        ;
    }
}
```

It worked fine, but when I open my editing form for class Person that already has value in cbCountry, cbRegion and cbCity, it does not show me the values of cbRegion and cbCity. Please, help me with this problem. Or show me the other way to implement this whole task.

Comment: your fiddle works for me.

Comment: If you're using jQuery to get/set value from the dom in an angular application, "you are already dead but you don't know it yet". Please provide your non working fiddle inspired from the one you're linking, will be easier to find the problem, this is probably a minor issue and the fiddle is the good way to do.

Comment: That was not my fiddle. I have found it when I was looking for solution for my problem, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345020/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection . And it does not work when I implement that method in my project.

Is there another way to do such depending dropdowns?