# How to return certain parts of a javascript array using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stuck on this for many a hour now and just can't figure it out D:

basic fiddle to understand the problem easier maybe http://jsfiddle.net/SWUeA/1/

I've got two select boxes (select_company and select_profile) basically when you select something from select company, the select profile box is enabled and allows you to pick something from there relevant to the select company box. I've created an array with 3 fake objects, as if it were a database.

```
   var PRIVILEGE_PROFILES = [
{ PROFILE_ID: "ADickinson", COMPANY_CODE: "GW", PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess", "AlAdmin", "DispatchAppAccess"), SECTOR: "01" },
{ PROFILE_ID: "CHague", COMPANY_CODE: "TP", PRIVILEGE_CODE: "DispatchAppAccess", SECTOR: "02" },
{ PROFILE_ID: "JWilliams", COMPANY_CODE: "XC", PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess"), SECTOR: "03" },
];

   var COMPANIES = [
{ Company: "XC" },
{ Company: "TP" },
{ Company: "GW" }

];
```

COMPANY_CODE represents the company_select thing, so the company codes are loaded into company_select box, say for example if XC is selected then that would load the name "JWilliams" into the profile_select. I've managed to do this using if statements, however I can't use if statements because there i'll be adding more things into the array and I can't just do 30 or so if statements for each company code. To get this to work the select box with the current_profiles loads the COMPANIES array and the Company in there would have to be equal to the COMPANY_CODE in the PRIVILEGE_PROFILES array.

```
  var companyselectHTML = "<select name='select_company' id='select_company'           class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
      "<option>None</option>";


var profileselectHTML = "<select name='select_profile' id='select_profile' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
"<option>None</option>";


for (var p = 0; p < COMPANIES.length; p++) {
    companyselectHTML += "<option value='" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "'>" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "</option>";
}
```

That's how my select boxes are generated and the basic loop which loads the privileges into it.
However this is where I get stuck, I don't understand how to get the loop to work. I had this which a kind user from here helped me with, it does load the PROFILE_ID into the select box, but only with IF Statements and I can't make 30 if statements. There must be an easier way?

```
   $(document).on('change', '#select_company', function () {
          if ($(this).val() == "GW") $('#select_profile').append("<option value='" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[0].PROFILE_ID + "'>" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[0].PROFILE_ID + "</option>")

    $('#select_profile option[value="ADickinson"]').remove();
});
```

so I tried using some kind of loop, but no luck. It doesn't return anything, it's probably wrong I'm not a very good coder. If someone could please help me, you'd be an absolute god.

```
     var Select = document.getElementById("select_company").value;

   $(document).on('change', '#select_company', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < PRIVILEGE_PROFILES.length; i++) {
            if (PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].COMPANY_CODE == Select) {
            $('#select_profile').append("<option value='" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].PROFILE_ID +      "'>" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].PROFILE_ID + "</option>");
           }

            else {
            $('#select_profile option').remove();
        }
    }

});
```

So if this made absolute no sense, i'll write a little summary.
User selects a company from the company_select select box
Then any COMPANY_CODE that is equal to the selected COMPANY will be displayed in the select_profile checkbox
Can't really use IF statements as I plan on adding more into the array if I ever figure this out.

Comment: Not really getting the full gist of what you're trying to do here.  Are you just wanting to "select" the `select_profile` based on what's happening in the `select_company` or must they be a circular reference?  i.e. if you select profile-x then you must also select company-x?  Can the profiles not be populated too as currently there is just `none` as the value.  Surely you want all the `options` in there and only actually `select` the correct one when a particular `company` is selected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate Dropdown 2 based on Dropdown 1 selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345020/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection)

Comment: Hi Rob, yes the select_profile should be able to be selected based on what's selected on the select_company. So for example if XC is selected in the companies box, I want that to load the only array option with "GW" in it from the PRIVILEGE_PROFILES into the select_profile box, which would be "JWilliams" as that he has a COMPANY_CODE of XC which matches the COMPANIES box. 

So what you say is correct, it's currently as none because I can't get it to work cause I'm not the best at javascript. I hope this clears it up

Comment: Where do you set the variable `Select` in your function?

Comment: Ooops, I missed that bit off sorry Barmar,

var Select = document.getElementById("select_company").value;

I don't even know if that was necessary, I was just experimenting stuff.

Comment: You're setting the variable when the page is loaded, not in the `change` handler.

Comment: Instead of the loop, it might be better if you made `PRIVILEGE_PROFILES` an object where the company codes are the property names. Then you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in your code:

1. You're setting `Select` when the page is loaded, not when the user chooses something from the Company Selection menu.
2. Your loop is removing *all* options from the Profile Selection menu when the loop finds a non-matching value in `PRIVILEGE_PROFILES`. Instead, you should empty the menu *before* the loop, then populate it with the matching value during the loop.
3. The `PRIVILEGE_PROFILES` variable is local to the `formatAppSelect` function, so can't be accessed from the `change` event handler. It needs to be in the scope outside both functions.

Working code ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j7w8r/4/))

```
var PRIVILEGE_PROFILES = [{
    PROFILE_ID: "ADickinson",
    COMPANY_CODE: "GW",
    PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess", "AlAdmin", "DispatchAppAccess"),
    SECTOR: "01"
}, {
    PROFILE_ID: "CHague",
    COMPANY_CODE: "TP",
    PRIVILEGE_CODE: "DispatchAppAccess",
    SECTOR: "02"
}, {
    PROFILE_ID: "JWilliams",
    COMPANY_CODE: "XC",
    PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess"),
    SECTOR: "03"
}, ];

formatAppSelect();

function formatAppSelect() {

    var COMPANIES = [{
        Company: "XC"
    }, {
        Company: "TP"
    }, {
        Company: "GW"
    }

    ];

    var companyselectHTML = "<select name='select_company' id='select_company' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
        "<option>None</option>";

    var profileselectHTML = "<select name='select_profile' id='select_profile' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
        "<option>None</option>";

    for (var p = 0; p < COMPANIES.length; p++) {
        companyselectHTML += "<option value='" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "'>" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "</option>";
    }

    profileselectHTML += "</select>";
    $("#profile_selection").html(profileselectHTML);

    companyselectHTML += "</select>";
    $("#company_selection").html(companyselectHTML);

}

$(document).on('change', '#select_company', function () {
    var Select = $(this).val();
    $("#select_profile").empty().append("<option>None</option>");
    for (var i = 0; i < PRIVILEGE_PROFILES.length; i++) {
        if (PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].COMPANY_CODE == Select) {
            $('#select_profile').append("<option value='" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].PROFILE_ID + "'>" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].PROFILE_ID + "</option>");
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks for explaining what I did wrong as well :) I'm adding a new function where depending on what is selected in the select_profile it will load that users PRIVILEGE_CODES into a div in multiple checkboxes. Will it be pretty much the same method with things changed?

Comment: Yes, the basic structure should be the same.

Comment: Hi Barmar, hope you read this. Using your method I tried adding a new person into the Array of PRIVILEGE_PROFILES who also had the company code XC, however it only loads JWilliams. JSFiddle of what I mean, can you help me out? ^^ http://jsfiddle.net/j7w8r/5/

Comment: I assumed they would be unique, my loop does `break` when it finds a match. Take that out if there can be multiple matches.

Comment: Oh, yeah that fixed it. Again my fault for the bad explanation, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/SWUeA/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var COMPANIES = [{
        Company: "XC"
    }, {
        Company: "TP"
    }, {
        Company: "GW"
    }

    ];
    var PRIVILEGE_PROFILES = [{
        PROFILE_ID: "ADickinson",
        COMPANY_CODE: "GW",
        PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess", "AlAdmin", "DispatchAppAccess"),
        SECTOR: "01"
    }, {
        PROFILE_ID: "CHague",
        COMPANY_CODE: "TP",
        PRIVILEGE_CODE: "DispatchAppAccess",
        SECTOR: "02"
    }, {
        PROFILE_ID: "JWilliams",
        COMPANY_CODE: "XC",
        PRIVILEGE_CODE: ("AlAccess", "AlBlockAccess"),
        SECTOR: "03"
    }, ];



    var companyselectHTML = "<select name='select_company' id='select_company' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
        "<option>None</option>";

    var profileselectHTML = "<select name='select_profile' id='select_profile' class='form_drop_down' data-role='none'>" +
        "<option>None</option>";


    for (var p = 0; p < COMPANIES.length; p++) {
        companyselectHTML += "<option value='" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "'>" + COMPANIES[p].Company + "</option>";
    }
    companyselectHTML += "</select>";
    $("#company_selection").html(companyselectHTML);



    for (var p = 0; p < PRIVILEGE_PROFILES.length; p++) {
        profileselectHTML += "<option value='" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[p].PROFILE_ID + "'>" + PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[p].PROFILE_ID + "</option>";
    }
    profileselectHTML += "</select>";
    $("#profile_selection").html(profileselectHTML);


    $(document).on('change', '#select_company', function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        console.log(val);
        for (var i = 0; i < PRIVILEGE_PROFILES.length; i++) {
            if (PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].COMPANY_CODE == val) {
                $('#select_profile').val(PRIVILEGE_PROFILES[i].PROFILE_ID);
            }
            /* else {
            $('#select_profile option').remove();
        }*/
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I gave you up an upvote cause it was almost what I wanted, but it loads all 3 instead of the selected one :)