# AngularJS - connect select inputs to show only related values after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm creating an Angular application and are showing my data using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).

The table has 4 columns (country, city, name, value).

```
Country       City         Name       Value
-------------------------------------------
Canada        Ottawa       Name3      100
Canada        Edmonton     Name2      94
Canada        Ottawa       Name1      66
Germany       Berlin       Name1      69
Germany       Berlin       Name3      32
Germany       Hamburg      Name1      71
USA           New York     Name2      42
USA           New York     Name1      52
USA           Los Angeles  Name2      176
USA           Los Angeles  Name3      143
...
```

I am using three select multiple inputs to be able to filter the data in the table.

```
<div id="country-filter">
    <label for="country-select">Country:</label>
    <select id="country-select" ng-model="vm.selectedValues.Country" ng-options="country for country in vm.filterItems.Country" ng-change="vm.selectionsChanged('Country')" multiple></select>
</div>
<div id="city-filter">
    <label for="city-select">City:</label>
    <select id="city-select" ng-model="vm.selectedValues.City" ng-options="city for city in vm.filterItems.City" ng-change="vm.selectionsChanged('City')" multiple></select>
</div>
<div id="name-filter">
    <label for="name-select">Name:</label>
    <select id="name-select" ng-model="vm.selectedValues.Name" ng-options="name for name in vm.filterItems.Name" ng-change="vm.selectionsChanged('Name')" multiple></select>
</div>
```

`vm.filterItems` is an object with arrays containing the possible values for each of the select inputs.

```
filterItems = {
    Country: ['USA', 'Canada', 'Germany'],
    City: ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Ottawa', 'Edmonton', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg'],
    Name: ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
}
```

`vm.selectedValues` has the same structure as `vm.filterItems` but contains only the selected values.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I select, for example, one (or more) countries in the first select input I want the other two select inputs to be updated and only show values that exist in the datatable after it is filtered (or disable the values that don't exist). The first select input should be unchanged. The user could likely have chosen to select values in any other select input with a similar result.

`selectionsChanged` function in the controller:

```
var filterCols = ['Country', 'City', 'Name'];

self.selectionsChanged = function (_selection) {
    var selections = [];
    self.selectedValues[_selection].forEach(function (selection, i) {
        selections.push('^' + selection + '$');
    });
    var regex = selections.join('|'),
        api = table.api();
    api.column(_selection + ':name')
        .search(regex, true, false)
        .draw();

    api.rows({ search: 'applied' }).data().each(function (obj) {
        filterCols.forEach(function (c) {
            if (c !== _selection) {
                var column = api.column(c + ':name', { search: 'applied' });
                self.filterItems[c] = getUnique(column.data()).sort();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

When updating `filterItems` it triggers the ng-change for all select inputs making the `selectionChanged` function be called three times. This also updates the select input that the user interacted with which I will prevent.

**Example**

If I select USA in the select input for the country I want the other two (City and Name) to be updated with all values not connected to USA disabled. In the example it would be 'New York' and 'Los Angeles' in the City select input that can be selected and all other disabled. Similar for the Names. The select input for the country should not be changed, still showing 'USA', 'Canada' and 'Germany' where only USA is selected.

How can the ng-change be prevented from firing when changing the filterItems within the selectionsChanged function? I only want the ng-change to fire when the user selects options in the select input.

**EDIT**

When selecting USA in the country select input (or a city in the city select input, or a name in the name select input) only the four rows with USA is shown in the table.

What I want is to update the select inputs for City and Name and disable all values that are not presented in the table. i.e only New York and Los Angeles should be enabled in the City select input and Name1, Name2 and Name3 should be enabled in the Name select input.

Only values existing in the table should be enabled in the table, except for the select input that was interacted with where all options should still be  enabled.

The options will remain disabled until the user selects an additional country (or whatever column the user filtered by), which will enable the cities and names now shown in the table.

Comment: `on-change` of first select call function and where you need to set values of next select.....

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify.

Comment: What i understand in your question is that you want three dropdown in which first is country and on selection of that you want state and on selection of that you want city right....?? if it is than `on-change` function on country dropdown in which it set values of state dropdown and so on...

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara I edited my question with additional information. Hopefully it is now clarified what my problem is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Xku9z/ this may help you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345020/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara Not exactly what I am looking for. My problem is more complex. I need ng-change on all my inputs, but when updating the ng-model it fires the ng-change event on all select inputs. I need the second (or any arbitrary) select input to be able to update the content of all other select inputs. e.g. the first select input will update content of second and third. The second updates first and third and so on.