# AngularJS populate dropdown based on data from another dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying do use [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345020/populate-dropdown-2-based-on-dropdown-1-selection) as a starting point to dynamically populate a second dropdown based on the selection made in the first.

What makes it a bit difficult is of course that I'm connecting to a MySQL-database to fetch my data...

This is the index.php-file

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="BlaBla">
<select ng-model="GetStartCategories" ng-options="category.data for category in categories1" ng-change="GetCategories2()">
</select>
<select ng-model="Get2ndCategories" ng-options="category.data for category in categories2">
</select>
```

the important part of the get2nd.php looks like this:

```
//DB Connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
$ancestor = $_GET["ancestor"];
$sql = "select * from cat_node n
Join cat_hierarchy h
on(n.id=h.descendant)
where h.ancestor = '{$ancestor}' and depth = 1
group by descendant";

//Use prepared statements as good practice
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

 //Execute query
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the results into an array
$result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($result);

//echo the JSON-string
echo($json);
```

with the following "pseudo-code" I'm able to fetch and populate the 1st dropdown:

```
function BlaBla($scope, $http) {
$http.get('get1st.php').
 success(function(data){
  $scope.categories1 = data;
  $scope.getCategories2 = function(){
    $http.get('get2nd.php?ancestor='+$categories1.id).success(function(data2){
      $scope.categories2 = data2;  
    });

   };
 });  
};
```

But the 2nd dropdown is of course not populated =)

Any suggestions?

Oh, for your info this is the Closure-table model:
[Closure Table Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWZKG.png)

Comment: What about `$http.get('get2nd.php?ancestor='+$scope.categories1.id).success(function(data2){ $scope.categories2 = data2;  
    });` ?

Comment: Hi! Still no changes!